# What does indices!= index_to_remove mean?

Tags: python, numpy, generative-adversarial-network

I’m supposed to write a helper function that returns a list with an element removed by the value, in an unchanged order. In this case, I don't have to remove any values multiple times.

This is the picture
[image of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0PrO.png)

And how do I understand the code here: new_indices= np.delete(indices,np.where(indices==index_to_remove))

Would highly appreciate it if there are examples to help me better understand the code.

Answer (score 0):

`indices!=index_to_remove` evaluates to an array of booleans, and we are using that boolean array to mask `indices`. See the numpy docs [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays)